# Passing parameters from Jenkins CI to npm script

Tags: node.js, npm-scripts, jenkins-job-dsl, pact

When I run Jenkins build, I would like to pass `COMMIT_HASH` and `BRANCH_NAME` to one of my javascript files: `publish.js`, so that I can remove hard-coded values for `tags` and `consumerVersion`.

Here is my code:

**Jenkinsfile**

```
stage('Publish Pacts') {
    steps {
        script {
            sh 'npm run publish:pact -Dpact.consumer.version=${COMMIT_HASH} -Dpact.tag=${env.BRANCH_NAME}'
        }
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "publish:pact": "node ./src/test/pact/publish.js"
}
```

./src/test/pact/publish.js

```
let publisher = require('@pact-foundation/pact-node');
let path = require('path');

let opts = {
    providerBaseUrl: `http://localhost:${global.port}`,
    pactFilesOrDirs: [path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'pacts')],
    pactBroker: 'http://localhost:80',
    tags: ["prod", "test"], // $BRANCH_NAME
    consumerVersion: "2.0.0" // $COMMIT_HASH
};

publisher.publishPacts(opts).then(() => {
    console.log("Pacts successfully published");
    done()
});
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass cli arguments to your node script which end up in your [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv).
Also npm passes on [cli arguments](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) via two dashes `--`.

To illustrate this consider this example:

**Jenkinsfile**

```
stage('Publish Pacts') {
    steps {
        script {
            sh 'npm run publish:pact -- ${COMMIT_HASH} ${env.BRANCH_NAME}'
        }
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "publish:pact": "node ./src/test/pact/publish.js"
}
```

**publish.js**

```js
// process.argv[0] = path to node binary
// process.argv[1] = path to script

console.log('COMMIT_HASH:',process.argv[2]);
console.log('BRANCH_NAME:',process.argv[3]);
```

I left the cli flags out for simplicity.
Hope this helps